# display character encoding in php

Tags: php, encoding

I have retrieve data from MySQL in php and post it to client: 
if I use `select * from users LIMIT 8;` 
no problem.. but when `select * from users LIMIT 9;` the last data retrieved broke the page.. when I debug in php I can see this data looks fine also:

`1 = "CN=User1,OU=ARGE,OU=Personel,OU=Kullanicilar,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=intra
2 ="CN=User2,OU=ARGE,OU=Personel,OU=Kullanicilar,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=intra
3 ="CN=User3,OU=ARGE,OU=Personel,OU=Kullanicilar,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=intra
4 ="CN=User4,OU=ARGE,OU=Personel,OU=Kullanicilar,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=intra
5 ="CN=Öney,OU=ARGE,OU=Personel,OU=Kullanicilar,OU=CompanyName,DC=company,DC=intra`

But there is no data returned from php.. its obvious that 'Ö' character cause this but I don't understand why its even looks true and my character encoding is:

My PageÖÖ

and this is also in top of my page :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

When I type a title '4 Tasks to completeÖÖŞŞŞ' in html of mypage.php it looks:
 '4 Tasks to complete��???' 
In stackoverflow it looks well, I want same for mine.. couldn't figure out the problem now in html or php or both of them?

EDITED: since I see in 'Öney' character in script variable I think in php page there is problem..

my connection settings:

```
$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webfilter;port=3306;connect_timeout=15', 'root', 'company');
            $this->dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Comment: *"But there is no data returned from php"* – what exactly does that mean?!

Comment: it means normally, in javascript variable I can see the returned data from php function..  but in that case(with 'Ö' character) this variable not set.. you got it?!

Comment: How does the data get from the debugger output you show into a Javascript variable...?

Comment: I set breakpoint 'return $result;' in php function and check the contents.. without 'Ö' all data set the javascript variable.. but when there is 'Ö' I simply press f10 and see the js variable not set.. so I figure that php couldn't post this string if it contains 'Ö, Ş, İ, Ü' I don't understand why its so hard to get it ?

Comment: **How does the data get into a Javascript variable?!** Not through magic I assume?! I'd rather bet there's some specific code involved which fails on non-ASCII data, no!?

Comment: but my problem not about php code implementation.. as I told its about character encoding if you look at post you can see the string array returned to client.. and you can see the answer below how a 'magician' solved my problem lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the charset as **UTF-8** in meta:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

But you're specifying **ISO-8859-1** in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

You'll need to have consistency, change the PHP header function to set the charset as UTF-8 too:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Other steps that might help:

1. Setting the file encoding to UTF-8.
2. Setting the table columns to be in UTF-8 (utf8-general usually works).
3. Running the query `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to the database.

Comment: yeah I tried the utf-8 in html but original in post I edited: if I make utf-8 in php 'Öney' looks '�ney'

Comment: What's the encoding on the file? You should save it as UTF-8 without BOM. If you're having difficulty finding where to set the encoding, post your code editor's name.

Comment: I use; PhpStorm 9.0.2 and php version is 5.6.15. I print 'Ö' in javascript it looks correct. so no problem in client but php..

Comment: At the bottom of the editor, where it shows you the line numbers and similar (on the right), you can set the file encoding. Check [this image out](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/files/2013/03/screen-shot-2013-03-18-at-41754-pm.png). Is it set to UTF-8?

Comment: I did it, but still if I change "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');" to "header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');" 'Ö' looks '�'

Comment: You will have to use UTF-8 if you want the characters to appear correctly. So, everything's at UTF-8 and you're still getting the error? What about MySQL then? What's the field encoding in the table? Is it UTF-8?

Comment: I changed to 'utf-8' header,editor and html. and MySQL table collation:'utf8-utf8_bin'

Comment: `utf8-general` should do it. So, do actually have all the characters in the fields? Are you sure the data is correct in the database? If it is correct, run the query `SET NAMES utf8` right after you connect to the DB with PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94582/discussion-between-mehmet-yener-yilmaz-and-satisfaction).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

to

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In HTML, `charset` is `utf-8`, but it is different in PHP. Make sure that they are same.

Comment: post edited I edited: but if I use utf-8 in php 'Öney' looks '�ney'